# Running a specific nodejs command as 'root' or 'sudo'

Tags: node.js, linux, permissions, wifi

I'm writing a small RESTFul API in Node with Express.js that, among other things, will provide me with the wifi access point details, including all SSID names, signal strength, frequencies, channels, etc.

I use the https://www.npmjs.com/package/wireless-tools node package to accomplish this.

The API works fine if I run the node program as root or sudo, but that is obviously not ideal and will likely not be allowed on whichever platform I have to deploy this. There are also other API calls in this app which should most certainly *NOT* be executed as root/sudo, so I need to find a way to elevate permissions only for this specific part of the API.

The code snippet that accomplishes this looks as follows

```js
router.get('/ssid',auth.verifyAccess, function(req,res,next) 
{ 
    var iwlist = require('wireless-tools/iwlist'); 
    iwlist.scan( {iface:'wlan0', show_hidden : true }, function(err, networks) { 
    if(err) 
    { 
        logger.error(self.type + ":" + arguments.callee.name, __line, `${err}`); 
    } 
    else 
    { 
        logger.debug(self.type + ":" + arguments.callee.name, __line, `iwlist scan initiated. Results:${networks}`); 
        res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json'); 
        res.send(JSON.stringify(networks)); 
    }
});
```

This gives output simalar to this:

```
[
    {
        "address": "e4:8d:8c:bc:f3:05",
        "channel": 10,
        "frequency": 2.457,
        "mode": "master",
        "quality": 70,
        "signal": -35,
        "ssid": "techedemic-Wifi-Dev",
        "security": "wpa2"
    },
    {
        "address": "10:08:b1:09:5b:1b",
        "channel": 1,
        "frequency": 2.412,
        "mode": "master",
        "quality": 64,
        "signal": -46,
        "ssid": "techedemic-WiFi-Prod",
        "security": "wpa2"
    },
    {.....
```

Assuming the application will eventually run as the 'myuser' user, how can I give the application permission to run the required commands, e.g. `iwlist wlan0 scan`, without having to run the entire API as `root` or starting it with `sudo`

Systems this should work on:
RaspberryPI, Debian and Ubuntu 16.04 or 18.04 and possibly other Linux flavours in future - all will support `sudo` if that is part of the solution.

I've tested it manually with all the above systems running as `sudo` user and all is well then.

Comment: One way that I have been able to achieve this is to use the `setuid` bit on the `/sbin/iwlist` and /sbin/iwconfig` commands. This allows *ALL* users on the system to execute the commands as root. I suppose that can work and is acceptable at this stage, but I was hoping I wouldn't have to give all users on the system access, just `myuser`

Comment: Idk but may be [THIS](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sudo-prompt#usage) will help you

Comment: Thank you @J4GD33P51NGH ... that worls for raw commands, but not when you use some kind of library that wraps the commands...

I'm going to use what I have in my first comment for now... it works fine